# Very unusual "cannot be applied" error

Tags: java, android, string, variables

Initially I'd like to say that I am a rookie at programming stuff:).
2 days ago a very strange bug occured in my application. In the FollowingActivity of my app. The fragment of my code saying

```
FollowingActivity adapter = new FollowingActivity(mContext, R.layout.layout_followrow, mFollowing);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

(mContext, R.layout.layout_followrow, mFollowing); is underlined and shows errors. One of them says : "FollowingActivity in FollowingActivity cannot be applied to" Then there are shown parameters. Two of them are ok but the last one(objects) is not. Expected parameter is FollowingRow and the actual argument is "mFollowing (java.util.ArrayList)" After that line "adapter" is also underlined and says "setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) in ListView cannot be applied to FollowingActivity" What should I do in such situation? Here is my code:

Comment: The third parameter of your constructor is supposed to be `List<FollowingRow>`. You're trying to pass `mFollowing`, which is an `ArrayList<String>`. A list of strings is not a list of `FollowingRow`.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of your `FollowingActivity` constructor is supposed to be a `List<FollowingRow>`. You're trying to pass `mFollowing`, which is an `ArrayList<String>`. A list of strings is not a list of `FollowingRow`.

Perhaps you want to convert your list of strings to a list of `FollowingRow`. In Java 8 you can do that with

```
List<FollowingRow> followingRows = mFollowing.stream()
            .map(FollowingRow::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(That's using your `FollowingRow(String)` constructor.)

Pre-Java 8 you can convert it with an explicit loop.

```
List<FollowingRow> followingRows = new ArrayList<FollowingRow>(mFollowing.size());
for (String str : mFollowing) {
    followingRows.add(new FollowingRow(str));
}
```

Then pass `followingRows` to your `FollowingActivity` constructor.

Comment: Ok but where exactly I should add that because it seems it did not help:(

Comment: Well, the first line of problematic code is not showing errors anymore, but in the second, "adapter" word is still underlined in red color

Comment: Can I get an answer?

Comment: I posted an answer to the problem in your question. I can't solve new problems in code I haven't seen.